# Would the distance to the cosmological horizon change if the value of the cosmological constant changed?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-constant

I intuitively understand that the distance from the Earth to the cosmological horizon (separating events that can reach us from events that never reach us) depends on the value of the cosmological constant. At the present value of the cosmological constant, this distance is about 16 billion light years. And if the value of the cosmological constant were many orders of magnitude smaller, the distance to the cosmological horizon would be greater?

Answer (score 1):

Two points.

(1) The current best estimate for the current size of the radius R of the observable universe (OU) is 45.7 billion light-years.  See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe .

(2) R is calculated by integrating the time T of a photon's traveling from the circumference of OU to the center (where Earth is) taking into account that the OU is expanding during the time that the photon takes (T = 13.772±0.040 billion years) to travel over this expanding radial distance. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe . What is integrated is the scale factor as it changes over time, and the scale factor depends on the four Omega densities, one of which is the cosmological constant symbolized as Omega_Lambda which is the density of the what is called dark energy.

Comment: What should be the parameters of the expansion of the hypothetical universe so that the distance to the horizon of particles is not 46 billion, but a trillion light years?

Comment: Your comment is a very difficult question to answer. It would help to put some boundaries on it. The expansion of the universe is based on a variable called the "scale factor" represented by "a".  "a" is a function of time: "a(t)". For t = now, a = 0. In order to know the size of something (like the observable universe) one needs to know the size at some earlier time t. You apparently want to compare two models: (1) is he model with four Omega variables. One can assume for simplification  that the curvature  is zero. The other three are the standard values for the current best fit model.

Comment: CONTINUING - If you want to understand the influence of dark energy, you must assume a value for Omega_Lambda which is is the range between 0 and 1. The current "best" value is 0.6911±0.0062. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model#Parameters .)  It is very unlikely that just changing the value of Omega_Lambda would produce a trillion light years.  I am guessing that possibly changing both Omega_m and Omega_Lambda and Omega_r=0

Comment: CONTINUING - PLEASE IGNORE THE ENDING OF THE PRECEDING COMMENT. I am guessing that possibly  setting Omega_r=0 and changing both Omega_m and Omega_Lambda, (note the sum of these two = 1), and choosing a specific time  when the temperature of matter is very very large,, and choosing a specific time for now (when a=1), THEN maybe you could get NOW might have an observable universe radius of a trillion light years.

Comment: CORRECTION - For t = now, a = 1.